# Liquibase Validation Exception: forIndexName is not allowed in mysql

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I have generated changesets from an existing oracle database. When I try to execute that changesets in a MYSQL database to replicate the schema, I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
     1 changes have validation failures
          forIndexName is not allowed on mysql, db/changelog/2019/001-initial_schema.xml::157562123123-12::sahilmehta97 (generated)
```

The changeset that is failing is

```
<changeSet author="sahilmehta97 (generated)" id="157562123123-11">
        <createIndex indexName="STUDENTID_UNIQUE" tableName="STUDENT" unique="true">
            <column name="STUDENT_ID"/>
        </createIndex>
</changeSet>
<changeSet author="sahilmehta97 (generated)" id="157562123123-12">
        <addUniqueConstraint columnNames="STUDENT_ID" constraintName="STUDENTID_UNIQUE" forIndexName="STUDENTID_UNIQUE" tableName="STUDENT"/>
    </changeSet>
```

I understand that MYSQL does not support forIndexName, but it was generated automatically using mvn liquibase:generateChangeLog command.
So what should I do to overcome this problem?

1. Is there any way using which I can generate MYSQL compatible changesets from oracle database?
2. Should I make changes to the changesets generated from oracle database?
3. Is there any way by which I can make the generated chagesets compatible to MYSQL, when I run the mvn liquibase:update command to update MYSQL database?

Or is there any other way?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the changeSet that fails

Comment: added the changeset that is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not guaranteed that a changelog generated from a database will work on a different database platform. While the Liquibase XML changelog format is designed to be database-agnostic, there are still some features that are database-specific.

If your goal is to create a changelog that is applicable to multiple database platforms, special care (and testing) must be done to ensure that the changelog works with those platforms. Describing all the different things that must be done would be very difficult.

In this case, I would alter the changeset to just remove the `forIndexName` attribute from the changeset. Then test this by using the liquibase `update` command to deploy the changeset to both an Oracle and a MySQL database to ensure it is doing what you want.

Comment: Is there any alternative to forIndexName that can do the same thing as it does? like using any other attribute like forIndexSchemaName or forIndexCatalogName?

Comment: You might be able to use the `modifySql` tag to accomplish what you want. It can be added to a changeset to modify the sql that is generated by another change in the changset. It can do this on a platform-by-platform basis, so might be ideal for this use case. See https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/modify_sql.html for more details.